# Tout de même - meaning

Tags: sens

I have read the following sentence in the book Le Petit Nicolas:

> D'accord, d'accord, ce que tu peux être contrariant, tout de même !

Context: a group of kids is playing Cowboys and Indians. One of the kids suggests they play a story where the kid X is an Indian and the other kids defeat him. The kid X does not like it and sulks in a corner. Then, one of the kids says the sentence above.

What does "tout de même" mean here? [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/tout%20de%20m%C3%AAme) says that it means "all the same", "anyway", "even so", "for all that", but those do not fit well in this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Tout de même !* is a set expression that marks an opposition, similar to *but*, *however* or *nevertheless*.

The sentence can be translated to:

> Okay, okay, but how annoying you can be!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct !

I'd add that *Le petit Nicolas* is a book in which the author took pleasure in transcripting all the "language faults, simplification and nonsense" children add in their sentences when they talk.
He did that to emphasize their childish behaviour and give his books a very unique feeling. As if you're in the child thoughts.

So careful about improving your french with these books. Some expressions/words are not used irl the way they are in the book.